# Jtabbedpane layout for button does not work

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

The below swing interface using tabbedpane works fine until i set layout for button, that is when i set the content pane loginpage to null (loginpage.setlayout(null)) the buttons disappear from the pane but works when i replace button with textfield or textarea.

```
package atmg;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class newgui extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public JPanel clickfn= new JPanel(),gui= new JPanel(),trasgui= new JPanel(),contentpanel = new JPanel();
    public static JTabbedPane Tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    public JButton loginpage, filloginfo,createlogin ;
    public JLabel label1 ,label2;
    private CardLayout cardlayout = new CardLayout();
    //static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    newguilogin nw;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newgui tf = new newgui();
        tf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tf.setSize(700,700);
        tf.setVisible(true);
        tf.setLocation(400,20);
    }

    public newgui(int a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    public newgui() {
        super("ATM");
        Initialize();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {

        nw= new newguilogin();
        nw.setgui(this);
        loginpage = new JButton("Go to loginpage");
        filloginfo = new JButton("go to fill log info");
        createlogin = new JButton("create a new user");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub



        actionListener a1 = new actionListener(); 

        loginpage.addActionListener(a1);
        filloginfo.addActionListener(a1);
        createlogin.addActionListener(a1);


        clickfn.add(loginpage);
        clickfn.setSize(20,20);
        clickfn.setLocation(50,50);
        clickfn.add(filloginfo);


        contentpanel.setLayout(cardlayout);


        contentpanel.add(Tabs, "tab");
        Tabs.add(clickfn,"panel1");
        //Tabs.add(trasgui,"panel3");

        this.setContentPane(contentpanel);

        cardlayout.show(contentpanel, "tab");
    }
    public class actionListener implements ActionListener
    {


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JButton src = (JButton)e.getSource();
            if(src.equals(loginpage))
                //threader = new Threading();

                //Tabs.addTab("panel2", gui);
                nw = new newguilogin();
                nw.initialize();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: but most of my design use null layout for pane , will try using grid or any other layout managers thanks

Comment: While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: Understand also that you can nest JPanels, each using its own simple layouts, and thereby create complex GUI's with simple layout managers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> that is when i set the content pane loginpage to null (loginpage.setlayout(null)) the buttons disappear

A good rule of thumb to follow with Swing layouts: never use `null` layouts.

While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Understand also that you can nest JPanels, each using its own simple layouts, and thereby create complex GUI's with simple layout managers.

Comment: changed the layout manager to Gridbaglayout and it works fine , will i be able to add scrollpane on to a tabpane,if we can please show me a example of it